# Is it possible to force CMake generate Visual Studio project on other project type generation?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmake, projects-and-solutions

I have a CMake project. It is a crossplatform project developed by a team of developers. Visual Studio and other make files are inside version control for library release and external developers.

Each time a file is added we need to recompile all project files for all platforms. How do I force CMake to generate new project files for all systems at once (if possible from inside CMakeLists.txt, not as command line arguments)?

Comment: Every version of visual studio generates a different version of project file.  VS6 was dsp, VS7 to VS9 vcproj - all different, VS10 to VS13 vcxproj - all different.  If you try to keep up with the different versions of visual studio, you'll be there forever.  Also, you have to consider whether it is 32-bit/64 bit, unicode/mbcs.

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend it, but since you're asking to *force* CMake into doing it: going by the assumption that the used generators and matching binary output directories are known you could do e.g. `if (FORCE_CMAKE)` `unset(FORCE_CMAKE CACHE)` `else()` `if (NOT "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" STREQUAL "Visual Studio 9 2008")` `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DFORCE_CMAKE=1 -H"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" -B"MyBuildVS2008Dir" -G"Visual Studio 9 2008")` `endif()` ... `endif()`. Just complete the list and each time one re-configuration is triggered it checks the others also.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't make sense for this to be possible within the CMakeLists.txt file. CMake is a makefile generator. Everything in the CMakeLists.txt file is configuring the makefile, and it can also be repurposed to make project files.

If the CMakeLists.txt file could also request to generate a different kind of makefile... it would be different from every other command in the CMakeLists.txt file in that it isn't describing the currently selected makefile.

If I were you I would just make a shell script, or a simple makefile, separate from CMake, which rebuilds each of the project files, by invoking CMake from command line with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal of the versioned CMake produced build scripts to not force developers to install CMake?

In any case: it's best to use the right tool for the right job. CMake is for producing build-files and the little scripting necessary to do so. Use a scripting environment (Bash, cmd.exe) to run CMake as necessary for all your platforms.

This keeps the CMake files clean (and readable, CMake scripting is hard to read) and provides clean separation of concerns.